# How to quickly jump between inline equations in vimtex?

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

Suppose I have a line of LaTeX code as follows

```
We have two equations $E=mc^2$ and $F=ma$.
```

How do I quickly jump between inline math equations? Let's say I'm editing the first equation `$E=mc^2$`, how do I quickly move my cursor to be inside the second equation `$F=ma$`?
Obviously I can do `fF` is this case, but I would like a more systematic way to help me navigate to the next `$..$`

Comment: As a naive start: `/\$[^$]*\$`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble But this will match `$ and $`, which is obviously not the desired jump target...

Comment: What about going backward? I tried to do something with `lookahead`, I don't know vim-regex much, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

### Combine [*vim-ninja-feet*](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet) and [*targets.vim*](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim)

#### Preliminary steps

1. **Change `$` from separator to quote**

   ```
   augroup mytargets
       autocmd!
       autocmd User targets#mappings#user call targets#mappings#extend({
           \ '$':{'quote': [{'d': '\$'}]},
           \ })
   augroup END
   ```

   I do not know how to make this change filetype-specific. If someone knows this, feel free to adjust this section
2. **[`vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) user**
   Since the OP has added the tag `plugin-vimtex`, I assume that the text objects `i$` and `a$` are defined by `vimtex`. To have consistent experience you should unmap them to use `i$` and `a$` from `targets.vim`. To do this add following lines to `~/vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

   ```
   " Unmap vimtex versions of i$ and a$ to use versions of targets.vim:
   xunmap <buffer> i$
   ounmap <buffer> i$
   xunmap <buffer> a$
   ounmap <buffer> a$
   ```

Now we can combine:

#### `z[`/`z]` + `in$`,`il$`, ...

To illustrate how this works, consider the line from the OP

```
We have two equations $<CURSOR>E=mc^2$ and $<JUMP HERE>F=ma$.
```

Return to normal mode when in the first equation and then press

```
z[in$
```

to jump at the beginning of the next equation and switch into insert mode.

You have many variations at your disposal:

- `z]` + `in$` jump to the end within the next equation
- `z]` + `il$` jump to the end within the previous equation
- `z]` + `2in$` jump to the end within the 2nd next equation
- ...

Unfortunately, at the moment staying in normal mode is not supported by `vim-ninja-feet` (see [issue 3 'Make it work in Normal mode'](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet/issues/3) on github).

#### Relevant excerpts from the docs:

`vim-ninja-feet:`

> ```
> z[{motion}              Enter |Insert| mode at the beginning of {motion}. For
>                         |characterwise| motions, this is like pressing `i`;
>                         for |linewise| motions, this is like pressing `O`.
>
>
> z]{motion}              Enter |Insert| mode at the end of {motion}. For
>                         |characterwise| motions, this is like pressing `a`;
>                         for |linewise| motions, this is like pressing `o`.
> ```

`targets.vim` provides many text objects and many variations of them, please consult the webpage and the full documentation. I just add the beginning of the section about the quote text objects:

> ```
> QUOTE TEXT OBJECTS                                *targets-quote-text-objects*
>
> These text objects are similar to the built in text objects such as |i'|.
> Supported trigger characters:
>
>     '         (work on single quotes)
>     "         (work on double quotes)
>     `         (work on back ticks)
>
> These quote text objects try to be smarter than the default ones. They count
> the quotation marks from the beginning of the line to decide which of these
> are the beginning of a quote and which ones are the end.
>
> If you type `ci"` on the `,` in the example below, it will automatically skip
> and change `world` instead of changing `,` between `hello` and `world`.
>
>     join("hello", "world") ~
>          └─────┘  └─────┘     proper quotes
>                └──┘           false quotes
>
>
> Quote text objects work over multiple lines and support |targets-quote-seek|.
> ```

Following features of targets.vim are in particular relevant in this context:

- [Next and Last Quote (also with counts)](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#next-and-last-quote)
- [Quote Seek](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#quote-seek)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a match for a `\$`, using a look-behind to match other equations enclosed in pairs of `$`s. That way you'll know you're always matching the first `$` of each equation.

This search will work:

```
/\(^\([^$]\|\$[^$]\+\$\)\+\)\@<=\$
```

See [`:help /\@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D) for the look-behind operator.

The rest of the regex should be (relatively) straightforward, the look-behind part is matching sequences of `$...$` or characters other than `$`. The look-behind is anchored at the beginning of the line, to ensure it's capturing all pairs in the line correctly.

It works as expected on the example you provided.

You can use ["very magic" mode](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv) to avoid having to escape so many metacharacters with backslashes:

```
/\v(^([^$]|\$[^$]+\$)+)@<=\$
```

You can also consider extending the match to the whole expression inside `$...$`, that way search highlighting will be more useful.

You can consider adding mappings to these commands (search it forward and backward) when editing LaTeX files, since typing the whole search expression is definitely cumbersome. Consider adding the mappings in both directions.

Comment: The mapping is just `/...` then you can use n and N

Comment: What about going backward?

Comment: @MahbubAlam What's the problem going backwards? It should just work, doesn't it? If it doesn't for you, can you be more specific about it?

Comment: @filbranden I took your mapping and changed it to `?...`, works fine when I am not inside a `$...$`. But if I am strictly inside a `$...$` the cursor goes to the beginning `$` of this math. I don't understand regex much, I tried changing your regex, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @MahbubAlam It works as expected to me. If your cursor is somewhere inside a `$...$` block, it will move to the first `$` in that block. But if it's already on the first `$` of the block, it will then move to the previous block. That way you'll go through all blocks using `n` or `N`. Perhaps you were expecting it to go to the previous block (instead of the beginning of the current one) but I don't see why moving to the beginning of the current block wouldn't be valid or acceptable behavior, to me it seems the most logical action... See also Hotschke's answer using plug-ins.

Comment: @filbranden If I am done editing inside a `$...$` block I thought it's natural to expect to go to the previous block altogether, then by `n` go to the block before that, etc. I was trying to achieve this, but coudn't in any way.

Comment: @MahbubAlam what's wrong with `2n`? It's not that different from if you're using `?\$` to match a `$` that starts a block. If you're past the start of the block, then `?\$` will go to the first character, same as this...

Comment: @filbranden I guess I was trying to find a solution that fits my idea of a 'perfect solution'. Anyway. It's not that I can't live with `?...`. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: I understand that this behaviour is the same as `w` and `b`.

Comment: @MahbubAlam Also same as `?word` goes to the `w` even if your cursor is in one of the other letters of `word`... So that's consistent with how `?` otherwise works and it's actually hard to come up with a regex that would go to the previous block directly... But see Hotschke's answer using vim-ninja-feet + targets.vim, I think that one does exactly what you want, if you use the `p` modifier for "previous" block...