# Delete text between two $ symbols in gvim

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex, operator-pending-mode

I understand that we can use `da{` to delete a whole `{}` block in vim. I am wondering if there is a corresponding version with `{` replaced by `$` (similarly for `di{`) as this would be very useful for people typing latex with vim (math enviroments are enclosed between 2 `$` symbols).

I tried to make my own

```
map da$ ?\$?<CR>v/\$/e<CR>d
```

but it's very slow.

Comment: PS prefer `noremap` variants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a mapping is quite hard to get right, including all corner cases.

Typically, you should try to use an "operator-pending" mapping to define the `a$` part, so you can use it in `da$` but also in commands such as `ya$`, `ca$`, etc. In fact if you define other custom commands that take a "motion", then `a$` will be a valid one.

A naive solution using an operator-pending mapping *and* assuming the `$...$` expression is in a single line (for inline math in TeX/LaTeX) would be:

```
onoremap <silent> a$ :<C-U>normal! F$v,<CR>
```

But this has some shortcomings, such as it only working from inside the `$...$` block (not from the cursor being right at the first `$`) or if you have two `$...$` blocks on the same line this mapping *will* select the text between the two if your cursor is on that region.

You can get Vim to use more advanced logic to select the delimiters for such a region very precisely, but that probably involves writing a Vimscript function to handle all corner cases correctly. (You can also do that to handle more complex matches such as a math environment covering multiple lines.)

Fortunately, there are plug-ins which can help you with that!

If you want to define your own, then the [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) plug-in can help you create new operator-pending mappings (and also visual mappings) based on patterns you define. This plug-in hides a lot of the complexity of these mappings in a way that avoids many of the pitfalls. Also, in many cases, using a simple regex to define the region to use as a text object is a much simpler approach.

If you're looking specifically into TeX/LaTeX, then consider the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plug-in, which already defines an `a$` text object for inline math structures. Also an `ae` for LaTeX environments, which you might find useful as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not against plugins, you can try `targets.vim` https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim

It has `$` separator text object:

```
SEPARATOR TEXT OBJECTS                        *targets-separator-text-objects*

These text objects are based on single separator characters like the comma in
one of our |targets-examples|. The text between two instances of the separator
character can be operated on with these targets.

Supported separators:

    , . ; : + - = ~ _ * # / | \ & $ ~

Separator text objects work over multiple lines and support
|targets-separator-seek|.
```

Comment: Maybe it is worthwhile to point out that a user can change `$` to become a quote text object in targets.vim. I have shown this in my answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23275/1292).

Answer (score 2):

## This solves most corner cases

```
onoremap <expr> a$ col('.') >= (col('$') - 1) && getline('.')[0] == '$' ? ':<C-U>normal! Bf$v,<CR>' : ':<C-U>normal! wBf$v,<CR>'
onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') >= (col('$') - 1) && getline('.')[0] == '$' ? ':<C-U>normal! Bt$v,<CR>' : ':<C-U>normal! wBt$v,<CR>'
```

Above operator-pending mappings solve most corner cases:

- cursor and `$` at the beginning of the line,
- cursor at the opening `$`,
- cursor in between `$ … $`,
- multiple white space in a `$ … $` block,
- cursor at the closing `$`,
- multiple `$ … $` blocks on the same line,
- cursor and `$` at the end of the line,
- closing `$` immediately followed by any other character,
- closing `$` at the end of the buffer,
- empty line.

What still remains possible, is to select text in between two `$ … $` blocks. In other words, there is no strict `$ … $` environment detection.

However, in my personal opinion, this is quite acceptable. After all, it saves one from installing a large plug-in, which may import other problems.
It comes in quite handy for editing TeX math formulae in Markdown.

Comment: Does it work on the last character of the *buffer*? What about if it's on a blank line? (Corner cases are aplenty with Vim...)

Comment: @filbranden Excellent comment! I updated my answer for these two additional corner cases. It works like a charm now.

Comment: Development of this answer essentially took place here at `vi.stackechange.com` To better understand how these mappings work, click [**here**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25096/3168) and [**here**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25122/3168).

Answer (score 0):

I tried these and seemed to work and be fast:

```
nnoremap ca$ f$vF$c "Change with $
nnoremap da$ f$vF$d "Delete with $
nnoremap ci$ f$hvF$lc "Change in $
nnoremap di$ f$hvF$lc "Delete in $
```

This assumes that you can't have a $ inside $..$. What it does is it searches for the first next occurance of $ then does a visual block. Then does a reverse search to find the previous $. Having selected visually the $...$ it just does a c for change or d for delete. Same for the 2 below which all they do is they move one to the left and to the right so it doesn't select the $.

Comment: As filbranden points out, with onoremap you only need two mappings

Answer (score 0):

You could also have operators for the next/previous pair of '$':

```
onoremap in$ :<c-u>normal! f$lvt$<cr>
onoremap an$ :<c-u>normal! f$vf$<cr>
onoremap iN$ :<c-u>normal! F$hvT$<cr>
onoremap aN$ :<c-u>normal! F$vF$<cr>
```

(With inside / around variants)