# How to ignore or silence errors in operator-pending mappings?

Tags: error, map-operator, operator-pending-mode

The following operator-depending mapping works great for me,

```
onoremap <silent> a$ :<C-U>normal! hEF$v,<CR>
```

except when it is issued at the very beginning of a line. What happens is that the `h` raises an error despite the preceding `<silent>` and the whole mapping gets canceled nonetheless.

With an operator-depending mapping, **how can such a trivial bordercase error be silenced or ignored?**

Here is a line to test it on:

```
$E = mc^2$ this is a test line with inline $\LaTeX$ math $\Omega$
```

### EDIT

At the end of the day, I solved [the original problem](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25108/3168) with a different mapping:

```
onoremap <expr> a$ col('.') >= (col('$') - 1) && getline('.')[0] == '$' ? ':<C-U>normal! Bf$v,<CR>' : ':<C-U>normal! wBf$v,<CR>'
```

Comment: PS `<silent>` different from `:silent`. The first simply prevents characters in the mapping being echo’d to the screen (ie, the command-line remains unchanged). The second actually silences errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be not to include the `h` in the mapping if you're on the first column:

```
onoremap <expr> a$ col('.') == 1 ? "f$" : ":<C-U>normal! hEF$v,<CR>"
```

*N.B. I'm not 100% clear on how you want the mapping to behave if run when the cursor is* not *between a pair of `$` signs. Some tweaks to the above may be necessary.*

Comment: The weird thing is, it does not work at the beginning of the line with the almost identical mapping `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? "f$" : ":<C-U>normal! hEF$lv,h<CR>"
` Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @SergeStroobandt How about this? `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? ":<C-U>normal! lvt$<CR>" : ":<C-U>normal! hEF$lv,h<CR>"`

Comment: Almost there! I have got now `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? ":<C-U>normal! lvt$<CR>" : ":<C-U>normal! hET$v,<CR>"
` and I am wondering whether one can extend the test for the character under the cursor at the beginning of the line; i.e. something like ` == 1 && char(col(':')) == "$"` I find it hard to find the pertaining documentation for these tests.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt I think you're looking for `getline('.')[0] == "$"`