# How to test whether the cursor is at the end of a line in a mapping?

Tags: cursor, map-operator, debugging, operator-pending-mode

I would like to test in an operator-pending mapping whether the cursor is on the last position of the line. I currently have this, but it does not work:

```
onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == col('$') ? ':…<CR>' : ':…<CR>'
```

**How can I test whether the cursor is on the last position of the line?**

Related to this:

- Where can I find the documentation of these tests?
- How can I quickly test such a condition from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
col('.') >= col('$') - 1
```

`col('$')` returns the number of the bytes in the cursor line *plus one*. Unless you have [`'virtualedit'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27) set, the cursor will never be in that position. (I'm using `>=` instead of `==` in case you *do* have `'virtualedit'` set.)

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by `these tests`, but you can find the documentation for `col()` at `:help col()`.

One way to test such a condition on the command line is to evaluate it as an expression and print out the result `echo`:

```
:echo col('.') >= col('$') - 1
```

Comment: I am actually looking for a good tutorial about conditional tests in mappings.

Comment: What I do not understand is how the cursor could be _beyond_ the end of the line. Could you explain that?

Comment: @SergeStroobandt See `:help 'virtualedit'`

Comment: @SergeStroobandt I'm not sure if any such tutorial exists. There are so many possibilities for things you could test! Having said that, they're all listed in `:help functions`, so having a skim through that might be a start.

Comment: Is there a way to evaluate these functions from the command line?

Comment: @SergeStroobandt Yes, `:echo` (see the end of my answer). In other contexts, you might want to use `:let` or `:call` from the command line.